# Why functional languages are amenable to parallelization?

Tags: parallel-processing, functional-programming

There is another thread titled "Programming language for functional parallelism: F# vs Haskell" in which the OP stated "Functional programming has immutable data structures and no side effect which are inherently suitable for parallel programming."

Jon Harrop, in his answer, argued that "Parallelism is solely about performance and purity degrades performance. So purely functional programming is not a good starting point if your objective is to get decent performance."

Well, I am not planning to go into whether functional programming actually improves performance or not; it seems that it is an implementation issue. What I am interested is on the conceptual level:

Are "immutable data" and "freedom from side effect" BOTH required for easy parallelization?  And are they sufficient conditions or necessary conditions? Are they more than necessary to guarantee data independence or commutativity?  References to academic literature is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> Are "immutable data" and "freedom from side effect" BOTH required for easy parallelization?

Mutation of data that could be observed from another thread **is** a side effect, so just freedom from side effects is enough. :)

> And are they sufficient conditions or necessary conditions?

Conditions for what?

These are *not* preconditions for employing parallelism. All that is said is that it makes things easier.

Look, it is like if someone said: *Java is inherently suitable for programming that avoids buffer overruns, because it doesn't have (manipulable) pointers.*

That doesn't mean you cannot write a program that does not overrun its buffers in C. It is just harder to do so.

Comment: 1. In another article "What is functional, declarative and imperative programming?" here, Shelby Moore III asserted that "referential transparency" is a more precisely term than "freedom from side effect" and that immutability of external values is a subset of the requirements for referential transparency.  So I guess can be used as a sufficient condition for parallelization.

Comment: 2. As to "condition", what I have in mind is something like Bernstein's conditions which are established as sufficient conditions for data independence.  If two computations are data-independent, they can be parallelized. That is, the Bernstein's conditions (and referential transparency too?) guarantees program correctness if the program is parallelized according to the conditions.  But since Bernstein's test is not necessary condition, program having computation parallelized without satisfying the test may still be correct.